# PHP - Dynamic URL

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, dynamic, ip

I have a link to a live video stream.

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/live/stream.m3u8`

I need to make that a dynamic link that always changes so I can hide / secure the IP from the users of the web page.

I see suggestions about making a hash out of a secret word and the users IP like this:

```
    $token = somehash($ip_address . $timestamp . $secret);
$url = 'http://site/' . $token . '/' . $timestamp . '/filename';
```

My question is... how does that link work?

You end with a link like this that does not point to your resource.

```
http://mysite.com/hash-code/time-stamp/filename
```

That link wont work because its not a valid URL.

Any tips?

thanks

Comment: The IP address identifies the computer on which the video resides. If you change the IP address, you change which computer the user's web browser will use when looking for the video. If you don't have the video on the new IP address, it will not be found. So, you cannot change the IP address. All you can do is change what comes after the IP address. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to hide the IP address? you can make it less obvious, but anyone can find it (DNS, WHOIS, etc).

Comment: I am trying to make the link change every time it is clicked on so that users have no way to view the stream after they log out of my site.    The link should contain a secret word known only on my web server or something like that.... or generate a unique token thats only good for that one time.      Thanks

Comment: You'll want to change your token/timestamp to querystring arguments (and the server hosting the video will need to be able to parse and validate those values) (e.g. "[http]://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/live/stream.m3u8?token=[token]&timestamp=[timestamp]"). You can also use Apache's mod_rewrite to automatically convert the /token/timestamp to a valid querystring address.

Comment: You could *also* add referrer checking on the server hosting the video to (sort of attempt to) ensure that users are coming from the link from your site and not directly visiting the page. That's not definitively secure, though... referrer headers can be altered by a user.

Comment: Yes, trying to secure the link to the live stream

Comment: Yep thats what I need.  To send a Token to the video server and have it authenticate it.  The video server would have to know the token before it could athenticate it.  The video server is a windows machine running wowza media server.    Thanks for your input.  I appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that for this, you need a considerably complex logic for the routing part. It might be advisable to implement this with a PHP framework that will handle custom routing for you, such as [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com) or [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/).

In Laravel 4, for example, you could define a route like this:

```
Route::get('streams/{token}', 'StreamController@showStream');
```

Then you would define a controller `app/controllers/StreamController.php` with an action like this:

```
[..]   
class StreamController extends BaseController {
[..]

public function showStream($token) {
    $ip = Request::server('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $url = Request::url();

    // do some hashing on the user's IP and $token (and maybe a timestamp)
    // compare it with the $url the user tried to view - not going to write that code for you :)

    if($allowed) {
        return View::make('your.defined.view.with.stream');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }        

    [..]
}
```

This is just a rough example, the actual code will take some more effort. But I'm merely trying to point you in the right direction. And I'd like to keep this answer reasonably short. Your goal can of course be achieved in a million different ways, with a gazillion different frameworks, but this is how I would approach it with Laravel 4.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It looks like this might work.  So in this example the token variable is just made up of the users IP, Timestamp etc?

Comment: You would have to calculate a token like that, and then give it to the user in form of a link like `http://site/streams/[token here]/`. Then, the user could call that link, the example controller would verify the correctness of the token, and if it is correct, give the user access to the stream. My answer did not include how to give the user the link that will let him pass. And on second thought, timestamps might be a bad idea.

Comment: thanks.  one last question.   what keeps users from being able to browse to the script file?  the one with the controller in it.  then once they browse to it they can see what the token should be etc.  How do you make the controller accessible to the web page but not browsable to the user?

Comment: laravel 4 handles that: all framework related PHP scripts (such as your controller AND your views) are outside the public HTML directory the users can access with their browser. they won't see your scripts. not possible unless someone hacks into your server.